# SQL Server: display only rows where conditional concatinated column is not null

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, reference, concatenation

Right, i have been fighting with this for a while now and though i have a working query it is bugging me that it is illogical. It's easier if i show what i mean:

I have a table with job i.d's, email addresses, and a boolean 'should be used' column.

```
CREATE TABLE LWEmail
(ID int, Email varchar(64), MustUse int)

INSERT INTO LWEmail VALUES(1,'adfgae@asfdvaerg.com',1)
INSERT INTO LWEmail VALUES(1,'sdfghsth@asfdvaerg.com',1)
INSERT INTO LWEmail VALUES(1,'admjury@asfdvaerg.com',0)
INSERT INTO LWEmail VALUES(2,'dyj@asfdvaerg.com',0)
INSERT INTO LWEmail VALUES(2,'adynee@asfdvaerg.com',0)
INSERT INTO LWEmail VALUES(3,'kitu@asfdvaerg.com',1)
INSERT INTO LWEmail VALUES(3,'aswtrhe@asfdvaerg.com',1)
INSERT INTO LWEmail VALUES(3,'abetr@asfdvaerg.com',1)
INSERT INTO LWEmail VALUES(3,'aeryje@asfdvaerg.com',0)
INSERT INTO LWEmail VALUES(3,'eyj@asfdvaerg.com',0)
INSERT INTO LWEmail VALUES(4,'dej@asfdvaerg.com',1)
INSERT INTO LWEmail VALUES(4,'aetyj@asfdvaerg.com',1)
INSERT INTO LWEmail VALUES(4,'ey@asfdvaerg.com',0)
INSERT INTO LWEmail VALUES(5,'egn@asfdvaerg.com',0)
INSERT INTO LWEmail VALUES(5,'egrn@asfdvaerg.com',0)
INSERT INTO LWEmail VALUES(6,'bneyh@asfdvaerg.com',1)
INSERT INTO LWEmail VALUES(6,'eryh@asfdvaerg.com',1)
INSERT INTO LWEmail VALUES(6,'adfeyj@asfdvaerg.com',0)
```

And a query that concatenates those email addresses into one line per ID depending on the 'MustUse' criteria:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
CONVERT (varchar(24), [LWEmail].[ID]) AS LogBatch,
STUFF((SELECT CAST(', ' + LWEmail2.Email  AS VARCHAR(MAX))
         FROM   [LWEmail] AS LWEmail2
         WHERE  LWEmail2.[ID] = [LWEmail].[ID] and [MustUse] = 1
         FOR XML PATH('')), 1,2,'') AS Emails
FROM   [LWEmail]
```

This produces:

```
LOGBATCH   EMAILS
1      adfgae@asfdvaerg.com, sdfghsth@asfdvaerg.com
2      (null)
3      kitu@asfdvaerg.com, aswtrhe@asfdvaerg.com, abetr@asfdvaerg.com
4      dej@asfdvaerg.com, aetyj@asfdvaerg.com
5      (null)
6      bneyh@asfdvaerg.com, eryh@asfdvaerg.com
```

I also wanted it to ignore the row if 'Emails' returned null (rows 2 and 5)
so logically i tried to add:

```
  WHERE Emails IS NOT NULL
```

At the end. This doesn't work: 'Invalid column name "Emails"'. But this does work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
CONVERT (varchar(24), [LWEmail].[ID]) AS LogBatch,
STUFF((SELECT CAST(', ' + LWEmail2.Email  AS VARCHAR(MAX))
         FROM   [LWEmail] AS LWEmail2
         WHERE  LWEmail2.[ID] = [LWEmail].[ID] and [MustUse] = 1
         FOR XML PATH('')), 1,2,'') AS Email

FROM   [LWEmail]

WHERE 
STUFF((SELECT CAST(', ' + LWEmail2.Email  AS VARCHAR(MAX))
         FROM   [LWEmail] AS LWEmail2
         WHERE  LWEmail2.[ID] = [LWEmail].[ID] and [MustUse] = 1
         FOR XML PATH('')), 1,2,'') IS NOT NULL
```

Why can i not reference 'Emails' as a conditional when i would have thought, due to the brackets and logical order, the execution path would make it one of the first things to be executed, making it available for evaluation? You can do this with, say, a converted date or a mathematical operation. Any insights? I would prefer to reference and evaluate something that has already been calculated, for efficiencies sake, rather than doing the calculation twice. Just looking to learn and be more efficient really.

Comment: Well that was easily solved! knew it would be something simple, just needed to force the creation of the 'Email' column before the WHERE could be evaluated by making it a subQuery. thanks for the quick response everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say "Logical Order", but logically, `SELECT` executes *after* `WHERE`. You can put it in  a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT
  CONVERT (varchar(24), [LWEmail].[ID]) AS LogBatch,
  STUFF((SELECT CAST(', ' + LWEmail2.Email  AS VARCHAR(MAX))
         FROM   [LWEmail] AS LWEmail2
         WHERE  LWEmail2.[ID] = [LWEmail].[ID] and [MustUse] = 1
         FOR XML PATH('')), 1,2,'') AS Emails
  FROM   [LWEmail]
) t
where Emails is not null
```

For processing order, see e.g. [Select (SQL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_%28SQL%29#Query_evaluation_ANSI) on Wikipedia:

- `FROM`
- `ON`
- `WHERE`
- `GROUP BY`
- `HAVING`
- `SELECT`
- `DISTINCT`
- `ORDER BY`

---

Also:

> I would prefer to reference and evaluate something that has already been calculated, for efficiencies sake, rather than doing the calculation twice.

SQL Server has got quite a few tricks up its sleeve where it can observe that the same calculation is being asked for twice, and will avoid *actually* performing the calculation multiple times. On the other hand, just because a calculation only appears once in your statement doesn't *guarantee* that the system won't actually evaluate it multiple times.

In this case, I'd agree to reducing it just because it looks messy. But you should be aware that in the SQL language, you're generally trying to tell the system *what you want*, not *how to do it*. That's the optimizers job.

Comment: Yeah, have done a bit of procedural programming (java, C++, etc), difficult to move onto a manipulative language without dragging over the thought-processes as well.  Thanks for the extra info.

Answer (score 1):

You obviously cannot call the `ALIAS` on the `WHERE` clause that is created on the same level. The `SQL Order of Operation` is as follows:

- FROM clause
- WHERE clause
- GROUP BY clause
- HAVING clause
- SELECT clause  (ALIAS is created here)
- ORDER BY clause

The `ALIAS` is created on `SELECT` clause and `WHERE` clause is executed first. The only solution you want to call from alias is to wrap the whole query in a subquery. eg,

```
SELECT  * 
FROM 
        (
            SELECT  DISTINCT CONVERT (varchar(24), [LWEmail].[ID]) AS LogBatch,
                    STUFF(( SELECT CAST(', ' + LWEmail2.Email  AS VARCHAR(MAX))
                            FROM   [LWEmail] AS LWEmail2
                            WHERE  LWEmail2.[ID] = [LWEmail].[ID] and
                                   [MustUse] = 1
                            FOR XML PATH('')), 1,2,'') AS Emails
            FROM    [LWEmail]
        ) subQuery
WHERE   Emails IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT
CONVERT (varchar(24), [LWEmail].[ID]) AS LogBatch,
STUFF((SELECT CAST(', ' + LWEmail2.Email  AS VARCHAR(MAX))
         FROM   [LWEmail] AS LWEmail2
         WHERE  LWEmail2.[ID] = [LWEmail].[ID] and [MustUse] = 1
         FOR XML PATH('')), 1,2,'') AS Email

FROM   [LWEmail] ) Sub
WHERE Email IS NOT NULL
```